# i am having this issue while calling static block in default.xml

Tags: magento2

Element 'body': Character content other than whitespace is not allowed because the content type is 'element-only'.
Line: 806

Comment: since you have copy paste code in xml so there is white space on tags so just remove all space before tag starts

Comment: i didn't copy any code i simply write code for static block which is present in admin panel

Comment: can u please share your code in question?

Answer (score 1):

create new static block

**for e.g** new static block id is : 22

```
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="contact">
       <arguments>
           <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">22</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
```